# JMeter JSON Extractor, extract all values of one key in a string

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

Using Apache JMeter ver 3.2 r1790745 (the latest) to test a JSON Web Service, the response is like:

```
[ {
   "id" : 3,
   "description" : "Back",
   "name" : "back"
}, {
   "id" : 1,
   "description" : "Front",
   "name" : "front"
}, {
   "id" : 6,
   "description" : "Left",
   "name" : "left"
}]
```

Want to parse the above response to get all ids in one string in JSON Extractor, like

```
3,1,6
```

My JSON Path expressions is like this:

```
$..id
```

But I got only the 1st id which is 3, the same result as `$.[0].id`
Checking the result in a BeanShell PostProcessor.
If I go to http://jsonpath.com/
$..id does give me

```
[
  3,
  1,
  6
]
```

Comment: I am getting `myvar=[3,1,6]` as you mentioned. I do not see any error in your syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you configure your [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) like:

[image: JSON Extractor Concatenation]

You will get the required value as `${foo_ALL}`

[image: JMeter JSON Concatenation]

---

I don't think using Beanshell is the best way to check JMeter Variable value, going forward I would suggest using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) instead, see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more details.

Comment: Instead of comma for the value separation,how can other characters used?