# How to iterate the foreach loop in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I got the array response from the one API and I passed to the response to the other API.
For example:
Response from one API is {status:200,data:{name:"Manikyam", selected_products:[1,2,3,4,5]}

I need to iterate the selected_products from the response using foreach or other loop which is suitable of this.

Iterations like:

http://dummy.com/product/1

http://dummy.com/product/2

http://dummy.com/product/3

http://dummy.com/product/4

http://dummy.com/product/5

I tried some ways like using forEach but I haven't any luck.
[image: extration from api response]

[image: foreach loop]

[image: each iteration]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878136/jmeter-json-extractor-extract-all-values-of-one-key-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below answer assumes that your response is a valid JSON looking like:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "name": "Manikyam",
    "selected_products": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  }
}
```

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `product`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.data.selected_products.*`
   - Match No: `-1`
2. Add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and configure it as follows:

   - Input variable prefix: `product`
   - Output variable name: `product`
3. That's it, if you add a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as a child of the ForEach Controller, the controller will iterate all the variables so you will be able to refer each and every as `${product}` where required like `http://dummy.com/product/${product}`

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Dmitri T.
It is working as expected